# convert multidimensional array into two separated

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional Array like this:

```
 Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( 
              [id] => 1 
              [name] => privilages1 
              ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
              [id] => 2 
              [name] => privilages2 
              ) 
     [2] => Array ( 
              [id] => 3 
              [name] => privilages3 
                ) 
     [3] => Array ( 
              [id] => 4 
              [name] => privilage4 ) 
     [4] => Array ( 
              [id] => 5 
              [name] => privilages5 ) 
)
```

and i want to compare it with another array, which looks like this:

```
Array ( 
     [0] => Array ( 
              [id] => 1 ) 
     [1] => Array ( 
              [id] => 2)
)
```

if the value of `id` matches, then i want to all values from the first example.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to filter the array elements you want by supplying a user defined callback function.

Here is the code:

```
$arr = array( array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'foo'),
              array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'bar'),
              array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'baz'),
              array('id' => 4, 'name' => 'wow'));

$ret = array_filter($arr, create_function('$el', 
          'static $search=array(array("id" => 1), array("id" => 2));
           $n=array("id" => $el["id"]);
           return (array_search($n, $search) !== false);'));

print_r($ret);
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => foo
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => bar
        )

)
```

Comment: If it worked for you then don't forget to accept this answer.